# How to make an Entity Framework query with a sum of the price that depends of the date?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have a question,

I want to create a query which is able to do the some of all price (which is a double), depends of the date.

```
--SQL Query
  select sum(price) from dbo.contracts where create_date ='2009-01-01' group by (id);
```

I tried this Linq query but it didn't worked :

```
--Linq Query
public static double getPriceFromMonth(int year, int month)
 {
    return unitOfWork.Contracts.GetAll().Where(c => c.create_date.Year == year && c.create_date.Month == month).GroupBy(c => c.id).Select(s => new { total = s.Sum(c => c.price) });
 }
```

I hope this isn't too complicated ^^'

Comment: You do not need GetAll().  Your SQL query doesn't make a lot of sense.  Returning an Array of price doesn't tell you what ID is associated with each price.  So I think you want a list of pairs which is the ID and the Sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
unitOfWork.Contracts.GetAll()
    .Where(c => c.create_date.Year == year && c.create_date.Month == month)
    .Sum(c => c.price);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you explain to me why I didn't have to group by while using Linq Query  please ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why you needed it in the SQL. I presume `id` in unique, so they'd be in groups of one. Even so, if you just want the sum of prices, does grouping matter? The sum is the same however they are grouped.

Comment: Also, as commented above, your `GetAll()` may be superfluous. But since it may well be something you've written, not standard code, I've left it in.

Comment: Thanks a lot really, and I will dig into it by myself :)